# Normal distribution - what is the mean and variance of this problem?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

Need help with the following.

Suppose that for a TV model it is known that 60% lasts more than 3 years, and 70% lasts less than 6 years.  Assuming TV life follows a normal distribution.  What is the mean and variance?

I will appreciate if someone can help and explain

Comment: Add the self study tag and maybe someone will give some hints as to how to solve it,

Answer (score 1):

Let $$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2),$$ where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ the standard deviation of the distribution. Then, from your data:

$$
P(X > 3) = 0.6 \iff P\left(\frac{X - μ}{ σ} > \frac{3 - μ}{ σ} \right) = 0.6 \iff
1 - P\left(\frac{X - μ}{ σ} < \frac{3 - μ}{ σ} \right) = 0.6 \iff P\left(\frac{X - μ}{ σ} < \frac{3 - μ}{ σ} \right) = 0.4 \iff \Phi \left(\frac{3 - μ}{ σ}\right) = 0.4
$$

Analogously, from $P(X < 6) = 0.7$ you may find $\Phi \left(\frac{6 - μ}{ σ}\right) = 0.7$.

Now, consult a standard normal distribution table. It suffice to find the corresponding $\Phi$ scores and solve the 2 x 2 linear system.